# From which row a data.frame variable have a constant value

Tags: r, time-series, dplyr

I would like to calculate the mean of a variable on a data.frame in R from the row which another variable start to have a constant value. I usually use dplyr for this database kind of task but I dont figure out how to do this, here is an example:

```
s<-"no Spc PSize
2                0           6493
2                0           9281
2               12          26183
2               12          36180
2               12          37806
2               12          37765
3               12          36015
3               12          26661
3                0          14031
3                0           5564
3                1          17701
3                1          20808
3                1          31511
3                1          44746
3                1          50534
3                1          54858
3                1          58160
3                1          60326"

d<-read.delim(textConnection(s),sep="",header=T)

mean(d[1:10,3])
sd(d[1:10,3])
```

From the row 11 the variable spc have a constant value, so this is the place I want to split the data.frame

```
mean(d[11:18,3])
sd(d[11:18,3])
```

I can calculate it by hand, but that is not the idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding a column that checks whether or not the entry matches the value above, then use `cumsum` to find the places where the count changes. I `group_by`'d that, and calculated the summaries you wanted -- I also added an output of which rows were included to demonstrate where it was grabbing from.

```
d %>%
  mutate(
    row = 1:n()
    , isDiff = Spc != lag(Spc, default = Spc[1])
    , whichGroup = cumsum(isDiff)) %>%
  group_by(whichGroup, Spc) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(PSize)
            , sd = sd(PSize)
            , whichRows = paste(range(row), collapse = ":"))
```

Gives:

```
  whichGroup   Spc    mean        sd whichRows
       <int> <int>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <chr>
1          0     0  7887.0  1971.414       1:2
2          1    12 33435.0  5486.794       3:8
3          2     0  9797.5  5987.073      9:10
4          3     1 42330.5 16866.591     11:18
```

If you only want the last group, which I can't tell from your post if you do or not, you could instead use `filter`, like this:

```
d %>%
  mutate(
    row = 1:n()
    , isDiff = Spc != lag(Spc, default = Spc[1])
    , whichGroup = cumsum(isDiff)) %>%
  filter(whichGroup == max(whichGroup)) %>%
  summarise(Spc = Spc[1]
            , mean = mean(PSize)
            , sd = sd(PSize)
            , whichRows = paste(range(row), collapse = ":"))
```

Which gives:

```
  Spc    mean       sd whichRows
1   1 42330.5 16866.59     11:18
```

Based on the comment, you appear to want the last group vs. the rest, you can get that with this approach:

```
d %>%
  mutate(
    row = 1:n()
    , isDiff = Spc != lag(Spc, default = Spc[1])
    , whichGroup = cumsum(isDiff)) %>%
  group_by(isLast = whichGroup == max(whichGroup)) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(PSize)
            , sd = sd(PSize)
            , whichRows = paste(range(row), collapse = ":"))
```

which gives:

```
  isLast    mean       sd whichRows
   <lgl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <chr>
1  FALSE 23597.9 13521.32      1:10
2   TRUE 42330.5 16866.59     11:18
```

Comment: I would like to calculate two groups, the last and the others.

Comment: @Leosar -- see latest edit for a version that compares the last group to all the others

Comment: It seems to me that this approach is more flexible than @Procrastinatus-Maximus one

Comment: @Leosar I think Mark's approach is a nice one, but it isn't more flexible imo (also not less flexible).

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:** Using `rleid` from the `data.table` package:

```
d %>% 
  group_by(rlid = rleid(Spc)) %>% 
  summarise(mean_size = mean(PSize), sd_size = sd(PSize)) %>% 
  slice(n())
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
   rlid mean_size  sd_size
  <int>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1     4   42330.5 16866.59
```

---

**Option 2:** Using `rle`:

```
startrow <- sum(head(rle(d$Spc)$lengths, -1)) + 1
d %>%
  slice(startrow:n()) %>% 
  summarise(mean_size = mean(PSize), sd_size = sd(PSize))
```

gives:

```
  mean_size  sd_size
1   42330.5 16866.59
```

---

**Option 3:**  If you want to calculate for two groups (last and others) you should use `group_by` instead of `filter` and create a new grouping vector (`rep_vec`) with `rle`:

```
rep_vec <- c(sum(head(rle(d$Spc)$lengths, -1)), tail(rle(d$Spc)$lengths, 1))

d %>%
  group_by(grp = rep(c('others','last_group'), rep_vec)) %>% 
  summarise(mean_size = mean(PSize), sd_size = sd(PSize))
```

which gives:

```
         grp mean_size  sd_size
       (chr)     (dbl)    (dbl)
1 last_group   42330.5 16866.59
2     others   23597.9 13521.32
```

If you want to include the rows, you can change the code to:

```
d %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(grp = rep(c('others','last_group'), rep_vec)) %>% 
  summarise(mean_size = mean(PSize), sd_size = sd(PSize), rows = paste0(range(rn), collapse=':'))
```

which gives:

```
         grp mean_size  sd_size  rows
       <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>
1 last_group   42330.5 16866.59 11:18
2     others   23597.9 13521.32  1:10
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find the index where the middle vector starts to be constant? You can take the `diff()` of your vector and look for the first time this is different from zero. For example,

```
vec <- c(1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6)
diff(vec)
differences <- rev(diff(vec))

# distance from the end of first non-zero
min.dist <- min(which(differences != 0))

# take difference
length(vec) - min.dist + 1
```

That last value should give you the index where the vector starts to be constant.